# the keydown events are not working on one of my projects but it is working on another project

Tags: c#

[Here is the image of the form properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyBRM.png)

i have the same codes of keydown events on two projects that i'm working but on my bigger project... the keydown is not working..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adv_v5.Properties.Settings.Default.destination = "stage2";
        Form7 bago = new Form7();
        bago.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adv_v5.Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
        adv_v5.Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    }

    int x = 100, y = 100;
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            x += 5;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            x -= 5;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            y += 5;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            y -= 5;
        }
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
```

`

this is the code on my bigger project... all the forms in this project, the keydown event is not working.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    int x = 100, y = 100;
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            x += 5;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            x -= 5;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            y += 5;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            y -= 5;
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);

    }



}
```

}
and this is the code on the test project.. the test project is working but the bigger proj is not.. i wonder if there's an error in the project properties or not... if you have an idea in where can i find my errors i gladly appreciate it. thank you.

Comment: Check your form properties - maybe, you didn't assign `KeyDown` event to the handler.

Comment: Keystrokes are delivered to the control with the focus.  A "test project" is somewhat likely to not have a control that takes the focus, so the form has the focus and its KeyDown event can fire.  For WASD key detection the simple workaround is to set the form's KeyPreview property to true.  However, if you also want to detect the cursor keys then you'll have to override ProcessCmdKey() instead.  Which is the universal way.

Comment: i do have assigned it let me edit my post and add a screen capture

Answer (score 0):

If you just copied the code into your new project you still have to connect the events with the methods you just copied.

Visual Studio did this for you when you first created the elements in your first project and connected the events with the methods.

To do that you need to go into the attributes editor (F4) and then select the small lightningbolt at the top. There you will see all the events the current element supports. You can enter or just select the methods and bind them to the events u need.

if you cant find it here is a screenshot:

[connecting events with methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hENBO.png)

Comment: same with above.. i did connected it to formKeydown event handler

Answer (score 0):

I add you screenshot, you must to go there and write the name of your method Form1_KeyDown on the KeyDown event name. It is best to do this first, press enter, and then write the code of the method

[image: Define a KeyDown event on a Windows form with Visual Studio]

Comment: i already do add it. there's a screen capture in my question i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

my answer to my own Question is the button. when the form starts the focus goes to any button. so the keydown does not work. but if there is no button in your form and only clickable label... keydown events do work.

Edit-
credits:
recently found out thanks to my professor.